Не могу сделать проект на flask
Установил flask, написал код :
from flask import Flask

app = Flask (__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"


@app.route('/about')
def index():
    return "About page"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

выдает ошибку

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'



Значит, не установили. Или не туда установили. Напишите, куда устанавливали. Используете ли virtualenv? Вы же понимаете, что деталей мало в вашем вопросе?

после ввода в терминале pip install flask пишет Requirement already satisfied по всем пунктам , при проверке установки (pip show flask) выдает нужные данные ,  а-ля версия и место Location: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python313\site-packages

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgAVGtkk03Q&t=200s
делал все , как по гайду из видео (единственное отличие , что делал в visual studio code)
но при запуске кода выдается одна и та же ошибка :
File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\project\app.py", line 1, in 
from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

Навскидку, у вас 2 возможные проблемы. 1) в настройках visual studio code указана другая локация установленного Python 2) вы ставили Python из Windows Store (я думаю, у вас Windows) - удалите его, скачайте с официального сайта установщик и работайте с ним. И, кстати, вы не ответили на вопрос про virtualenv

пайтон устанавливал с оф. сайта, про настройки вузаулки не знаю особо , только начинаю познавать основы так сказать... про virtualen - только что скачал

Приветствую! Мысль промелькнула, а не могла возникнуть путаница между pip и pip3 (python2 и python3 соответственно)? Или это только в linux возможно?

@HerrAskin Под виндой тоже может быть много разных окружений питона, причём даже одной глобальной версии. И разной или одинаковой конкретной версии с разным набором библиотек.
